# rails + carrierwave S3: force link_to to download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Question:

I would like to force link_to to download images and pdfs fetched from S3 instead of opening them in the browser window.

```
link_to File.basename(asset.attachment.path), asset.attachment_url.to_s
```

I looked for solutions but the only ones I found are to handle it in the controller using send_file or send_data but these did not work for me. Finally I stumbled upon the solution in Carrierwave sources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

This is what works super well. Use 'response-content-disposition' as a parameter to url

```
link_to File.basename(asset.attachment.path), asset.attachment_url(:query => {"response-content-disposition" => "attachment"}).to_s
```

Find more options here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/5aec4725a94fca2c161e347f02b930844d6be303/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb (line 185)

Comment: Note instead of File.basename(..) you can replace with file_identifier

Comment: This solution did not work for me.  Code below seems to ignore the disposition and redirects the entire page rather than just downloading the file.

`link_to attachment.file_identifier, attachment.file_url(:query => {"content-disposition" => "attachment"}).to_s`

Answer (score 7):

You can default this for all files of a particular uploader by adding a fog_attributes method.

e.g.

```
# your_uploader.rb
def fog_attributes
  {'Content-Disposition' => "attachment"}
end
```

This works with requests that aren't signed as well!